# All the included window get/set called when parent Window loaded.How to fix it so included window get/set call when Included Window call?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

Generally we are including any JSF/XHTML page like this in other pages Let us suppose i have included `include_popup.xhtml` page inside `parent.xhtml` page.

```
<ui:include src="include_popup.xhtml" >
             <ui:param name="parentBean" value="#{beanName}" />
</ui:include>
```

As you can check included window is a popup page which will be open when user will do some `action`

```
<a4j:commandButton   value="ButtonName" action="#{beanNaem.callSomeMethod}" oncomplete="#{rich:component('popup')}.show(true)" >
</a4j:commandButton>
```

But when `parent.xhtml` will be rendered at the time all the get/set of `include_popup.xhtml` also called . But popup Window will be open when I will click on `Button` ..Now my issue is that I have to initialize some variable of PopupBean when I am clicking on the `Button`  but as get/set already called when `parent.xhtml` load now if I will give some new values to variable of PopUp Window with `action` fired its wont effect update the Popup Bean variable so old value will be display .

So how can this issue will be resolve..I have to use conditional render for popup window? put this  inside some other component then use render attribute or something else I can do?

**Note:-** My Popup Bean have `Request Scope` and ParentBean `session scope`

Comment: So here rather than directly using `<ui:include>` its good to add this under some `panel` and render that on `button` click?

Comment: I changed the title of the question.